# I cant seem to get my listView for android working

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am working along with a book (The big nerd ranch guide, Android) and i am trying to get a listView working. It has worked in the past and i dont believe i have changed any code, but when i run my application it only shows a blank page. And like i said earlier, I did have a listView working completely before, with this same code. Here is the main code that i have:

// If there is any other classes or files you would like to see, leave a comment and i can add the code.

```
public class CrimeListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String Test = "CrimeListFragment";
    private ArrayList<Crime> mCrimes;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.crimes_title);

        mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();
        CrimeAdapter adapter = new CrimeAdapter(mCrimes);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Crime c = ((CrimeAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), CrimeActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private class CrimeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Crime> {

        public CrimeAdapter(ArrayList<Crime> crimes) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, crimes);    
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, null);
            }

            Crime c = getItem(position);

            TextView titleTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_titleTextView);
            titleTextView.setText(c.getTitle());
            TextView dateTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_dateTextView);
            dateTextView.setText(c.returnDate());
            CheckBox solvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_solvedCheckBox);
            solvedCheckBox.setChecked(c.isSolved());

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. This problem has been going on for a few weeks and is very frusturating. Thank you all!

Comment: mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes(); Does mCrimes have anything in it at this point?

Comment: you have to override `getCount`and return the count of items.

Comment: yes, mCrimes does have a list of Crime objects already in it. @user2045570

Comment: @Raghunandan. Is getCount used set up how large the listView is? And where would i Override this?

Comment: no its for the number of items to be displayed in listview.

Comment: I overrided getCount to return the number of items in mCrimes. Still a blank page when it runs.

Comment: `mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes()` is the size of mCrimes greater than 0?.

Comment: yes it is greater than 0. But if it were 0, would there be no list?

Comment: I would also try to replace `mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes()` with `ArrayAdapter<Crime> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Crime>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mCrimes)`. And it will still give me a blank page

Comment: Try to use BaseAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter<Crime>, and logcat in getCount() and getView() to see what happening there.